# Not retrieve data from database

Tags: c#, oledb

I've tried build and run this code but it always send me Error: 'cause not retrieve data from database. 
My code have no error after I build it. I've been search but I can't see something wrong about it. 
I hope I can find some answer for this situation. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string ProviderName = null;
            string CatalogName = null;
            string DataSourceName = null;
            string ConnectionString = null;
            string CommandString = null;
            const int MaxRows = 100;

            ProviderName = "Provider=Something;";
            CatalogName = "Catalog=Something;";
            DataSourceName = "DataSource=Something";

            ConnectionString = ProviderName+CatalogName+DataSourceName;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            CommandString = "Something";

            OleDbConnection DBConnection = null;
            try
            {
                DBConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            }catch (Exception ex){

            MessageBox.Show("Error: Not connected. \n{0}", ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                OleDbCommand DBCommand = new OleDbCommand(CommandString, DBConnection);
                DBConnection.Open();


                OleDbDataReader DBReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                DateTime DBTimestamp = new System.DateTime();
                Double DBValue = new System.Double();
                int DBQualityCode;
                int DBFlags;
                String ColumnEntry;

                listView1.View = View.Details;
                listView1.GridLines = true;
                listView1.TabIndex = 0;
                listView1.Width = 400;

                listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
                listView1.Columns[0].Text = ("Timestamp");
                listView1.Columns[0].TextAlign = (HorizontalAlignment.Center);
                listView1.Columns[0].Width = 150;


                listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
                listView1.Columns[1].Text = ("Value");
                listView1.Columns[1].TextAlign = (HorizontalAlignment.Center);
                listView1.Columns[1].Width = 60;


                listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
                listView1.Columns[2].Text = ("Quality Code");
                listView1.Columns[2].TextAlign = (HorizontalAlignment.Center);
                listView1.Columns[2].Width = 60;


                listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
                listView1.Columns[3].Text = ("Flags");
                listView1.Columns[3].TextAlign = (HorizontalAlignment.Center);
                listView1.Columns[3].Width = 60;

                ListViewItem SingleRow;

                int count = 0;

                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

               while ((DBReader.Read() && (count < MaxRows)))
                {
                    DBTimestamp = DBReader.GetDateTime(1);
                    DBValue = DBReader.GetDouble(2);
                    DBQualityCode = DBReader.GetInt32(3);
                    DBFlags = DBReader.GetInt32(4);

                    //////////////////////////////////////

                    ColumnEntry = String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss}{1:D2}", DBTimestamp, DBTimestamp.Millisecond);
                    SingleRow = new ListViewItem(ColumnEntry);

                    ColumnEntry = String.Format("{0:F}", DBValue);
                    SingleRow.SubItems.Add(ColumnEntry);

                    ColumnEntry = String.Format("{0:X2}", DBQualityCode);
                    SingleRow.SubItems.Add(ColumnEntry);

                    ColumnEntry = String.Format("{0:X4}", DBFlags);
                    SingleRow.SubItems.Add(ColumnEntry);

                    listView1.Items.Add(SingleRow);

                    count = count + 1;
               }
               DBReader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error:Failed to retrive Data From Database. \n{0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

                DBConnection.Close();

            }    
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the detail error message?

Comment: It just said **OleDbExeption was Unhandled** No error Message Available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Comment: can you post the stacktrace ? MessageBox.Show("Error:Failed to retrive Data From Database. \n{0}", ex.StackTrace);

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDB.OleDBException' occured in System.Data.dll

Comment: You are passing the user and password information in the connection string right?

Comment: Check that your connection string is correct, by connecting to the database in the Sevrer Explorer, and obtaining the con string from its properties. You need to step through your code and find the line it breaks at.